# How do I leave "My party" in Halo Reach

Tags: halo-reach

When in the menu in Halo Reach, how do I leave the party? We are currently two and cant therefore go in to theater mode. And I cant figure out how to make one player leave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Press the Xbox 'Guide' button (the big X-logo button in the middle of
   the controller)
2. Press `X` to leave the party
3. Continue to theatre mode and enjoy your movie!

If you have any more questions, take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959939).

Comment: Thank you, now I don't have to restart my console for this anymore! I've edited the step that wasn't necessary!

Comment: glad I could help :)